# Why file is not converted to base64 in Html while sending to server

Tags: php, android, html

I am just curious and I want to know that:

Say in a form, input type is File

```
    <form>
        <input  type="file"></input>
   </form>
```

You can access this file using **$_File** in php. You are not doing any conversion but in android while transfering the same File you will have to convert it to Bitmap or BinaryFormat and I know why we should do that. I want to know why aren't we doing this in Html.

Comment: `using $_File in php`. ??? There is no $_File in php. `you will have to convert it to Bitmap`. No. Not at all.  `or BinaryFormat`. But then there is no conversion.

Comment: You want to know something about base64?

Comment: i am sorry it's actually $_FILES. I know what is  base64 i want to know if file is converted to base64 or not

Comment: By who? And when should that happen and why?